# Calculate volume from crossections

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

I have an irregularly shaped 3d object. Of this object I know the areas of the crossections in regular intervals. How can I calculate the volume of this object?

Comment: Language-agnostic questions like this might be better asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can only approximate the volume. Just add up all the areas and then multiply by the distance between intervals.

Obviously the smaller the distance between intervals, the more accurate the volume. It is just integration (calculus).

Answer (score 1):

Discretize it using tetrahedra or bricks and add up their volumes, a la finite element methods.  Integrate using Gaussian quadrature and sum.

Answer (score 1):

You're estimating a Riemann integral.  There are many methods to do this, of varying complexity.  [Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) is reasonably straightforward and will be pretty accurate as long as the cross-sectional area varies in a smooth enough fashion, however it requires that the number of intervals be even.

Comment: If the intervals are equal (regular) as the OP says, then Simpson's rule is a good choice, but [the trapezoid rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) doesn't require an even number of intervals (or equal intervals), and so will be more robust in many applications.

Answer (score 1):

Ed Heal's answer is a Riemann sum that approaches the (volume) integral in the limit.  Depending on where the cross-sections are located with respect to the extent of the object, it might be viewed as an application of [the midpoint rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method).

Assuming the cross-section area varies smoothly with distance (twice continuously differentiable along the axis perpendicular to the cross-sections), the midpoint rule and trapezoid rule have accuracy that improves with the *square* of the interval width (here assumed regular).  Averaging the midpoint and trapezoid rule approximations amounts to an application of Simpson's rule, outlined in Peter Milley's answer, with higher order accuracy (improving with the fourth power of the interval width) *provided* the integrand is sufficiently smooth (continuous 4th derivative of cross-section area with respect to distance).

Of course many real world figures will not have such smoothness (too many corners, holes, etc.), so it is prudent not to expect exceptional accuracy from making more sophisticated approximations.